# Unix script to kill a process after checking a condition several times and also run periodically

Tags: unix, kill, pstack

I want to write a unix shell script to run a command 3 times in every 80 seconds and write the every sequence in a different line in a text file. And also if the all results are 10 or more in a line I want to kill the process:

for example:

```
pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

5

pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

5

pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

5

//Nothing to do.

//after 80 seconds again it runs:

pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

10 

pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

10

pstack <pid> | grep -c 'abcd'

10

kill -9 < PID>     // because all three outputs are bigger than 10
```

also

the output file:

```
5 5 5 

10 10 10
```

Note the if the output sequence is "10 10 11", "10 11 12" etc. then the process should be killed again. But if it is like "9 9 10" then no need to be killed.

Answer (score 1):

What *are* you trying to achieve?

Sounds like an extremely hacky way to monitor a process. 
Couldn't you simply employ:

```
ulimit -T 10    # the maximum number of threads
```

or a variation  (`man bash` , <kbd>/</kbd>ulimit<kbd>Enter</kbd>)?

That way a program could even possibly be more graceful in shutting itself down.

---

*Note*: since you suggest using `kill -9` without trying other signals, perhaps you imply that signals never get handled? In that case you can probably use `ulimit -i` (*the maximum number of pending signals*)

#### Snippet

```
#!/bin/bash

function dumpstack()
{
    pstack $(pgrep a.exe) | grep -c abcd
}

while sleep 1; do dumpstack; done | tee rawoutput.log |
    {
        trap "" INT
        count=0;
        while read stackframes; do 
            if [[ $stackframes -lt 10 ]]; then
                count=0
            else
                count=$(($count+1))
            fi

            if [[ $count -ge 3 ]]; then
                echo KILL -9 !
                            break
            fi
            echo "(debug frames:$stackframes, count:$count)"
        done
    } | tee cooked_output.log
```

Comment: The way I described is a must :( I am trying to count the number of  specific lines in the pstack output and decide to kill or not to kill according to the last three results.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. I think it's hacky, and suggest other ideas. Feel free to ignore them :). If you don't want to deliberate, just code it

Comment: posting a snippet that does what you want assuming bash shell

Comment: Actually I have to add something to this code to check the pid of the "a.exe" everytime before running pstack. such as:

pstack `ps -aef | grep 'a.exe' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`| grep - c "abcd"

But there is something wrong with this query and I don't know how to add it inside the above...

Comment: Also I have an idea it can check the sum of the last three output every time if it is equal or bigger than 30 it can run the kill...

Comment: Yeah I thought of the sum. However, like you said `The way I described is a must :(`. The sum of 99 + 0 + 0 > 30, but doesn't satisfy your own criteria :) -- If you are on linux, `pstack $(pgrep a.exe)` will do what you want (perhaps use `pgrep a.exe|sort -n|head -n1` to get the first pid only)

Comment: Well, have you tried? `pgrep` works on my OpenSolaris `SunOS bbs2 5.11 snv_134 i86pc i386 i86pc`. It lives in `/usr/bin/pgrep` so I'm pretty sure it's not from blastwave or community software

Comment: pstack $(pgrep a.exe) | grep -c abcd  is working...Also I am trying to keep the ouputs in a file... because I have to investigate the system. 10 10 10 is a risky sequence but there might be unexpected problems during a 9 9 9 sequence...

Comment: ok, I jotted in a 'tee rawoutput.log |' just to demonstrate how to 'keep output in a file'

Comment: thank you very much I got the idea but unfortunately:

"line 4: seq: command not found "  :(

Comment: Ok, simplified the answer to remove confusing bits. -- That's kind of funny, **obviously** you didn't that (obvious by virtue of a helpful comment sitting on the line directly above it <-- now removed)

Comment: @ephieste: Re: `ok I ignore...` No! That's not right. I edited the answer. Please don't cripple the script by ignoring errors. [You'll simply make it not work without seeing it](http://www.ostrichheadinsand.com/images/ostrich-head-in-sand.jpg?dur=125)